# Solve a linear system for FFT coefficients

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, fortran, octave

If I wanted to integrate the heat equation in a periodic domain using FT in (2d) space, using Crank-Nicolson I would write:

```
(1-kappa*dt*L/2)ftT(now)=(1+kappa*dt*L/2)ftT(last)
```

where L is an array of numbers that scale the solution ftT into its Laplacian.
 This is simple to solve with LAPACK if the ftT arrays are square, as they are in Matlab/Octave.
 Using FFTW in the r2c,c2r mode however, the complex array of transforms is not square.  It is simple to see how to modify L to handle that part of the non-squareness, and it is clear how to fill in the ftT array to make it square, but that seems wasteful. I have not been able to come up with a way to solve the non-square linear system.  I am hung up on the idea that for such a system, the number of equations has to equal the number of variables. Has anyone had to deal with this problem?

Comment: *"It is simple to see how to modify L to handle that part of the non-squareness,..., but that seems wasteful."* Why? That is exactly what I would do.

Comment: Also, I don't see any real linear system to be solved with LAPACK. There is no matrix multiplication in your equation. They are just simple separate algebraic equations, no system. That is the whole point of the Fourier transform, to avoid complicated systems.

Comment: This might get better answers over at https://scicomp.stackexchange.com.  But it might also get comments like the ones that @VladimirF has already made too.

Comment: @VladimirF The linear system I described was to solve the equation I wrote fro ftT(now), so in 'A*x=B', the A is '(1-kappa*dt*L/2)'.  I guess I am not sure I understand the distinction between "simple algebraic equations" and a system of linear equations.  Anyway, I will either fill in or retreat to c2c.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I will take all VladimirF comments gladly..   Thanks for the link.

Comment: @ClintonWinant Please do not crosspost to the other site. You can post there and delete here, but never cross-post.

Comment: @VladimiF  ooops just cross-posted, I will try to remove there, dont know how to delete here

Comment: You can't delete here any more. You are welcome to ask at https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ a new question. But don't forget to include more details. Show all the operators you have so that they see where does the matrix come from. Do not just repeat the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is NO linear system to be solved. For the Laplacian (unlike other operators) the Fourier modes are eigenvectors.

Therefore after the Fourier transform the Fourier modes are independent, all are solution of the linear PDE.

Your equation:

```
(1-kappa*dt*L/2) ftT(now) =(1+kappa*dt*L/2) ftT(last)
```

would be a (potentially complicated) linear system if L was a non-diagonal matrix. That would happen for the advection operator for example.

But for the Laplacian it is a collection of simple algebraic equations, `L` is a diagonal matrix and you only work with the diagonal terms - the eigenvalues.

For every `i = 1..n` :

```
(1-kappa*dt*L(i)/2) ftT_now(i) =(1+kappa*dt*L(i)/2) ftT_last(i)
```

is ONE algebraic equation with **ONE UNKNOWN** number `ftT_now(i)`. All other terms in the equation are just numbers. No matrices in sight.

So you just find the appropriate eigenvalues `L(i)` corresponding to each Fourier mode `ftT(i)` and compute the simple equation.

---

It does not matter whether you use `R2C`, or `C2C`. Whether the table with the eigenvalues is square or non-square. There is no linear system for LAPACK in sight.

Comment: I get your point, unfortunately as you guessed (one more time), there is another term: the integral of the jacobian.  I am really integrating the vorticity equation.  I cast the question the way I did because I wanted to keep it simple, throwing the babe out with the wash.. No worries, I will go to c2c.

Comment: But that will not change that much I think. But might be easier to start.

Comment: And be sure to look for sparse matrix solvers if your matrix is sparse, which is quite likely.

Comment: The 'A' part is 1 + the array of numbers that transform a variable into its laplacian, so the entries are like k**2 and l**2, or sums; the matrix is not sparse, but it is highly repeaatble, I suppose that doesn't help.

Comment: You can ask at scicomp, with as many details as you have. There are people with a lot of experience. But they need those details, like the structure of the matrix and where it comes from.

Comment: I worked through everything and finally got it.  It seems magical: I thought the nonlinearities represented by the Jacobian would result in moving energy from one wavenumber to the next.  They do of course, but it has nothing to do with the equation I wrote.  I am grateful for your hanging in there...